# How to submit the game made with Cocos 2d v2.1 to the Apple App Store

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, submit

I developed the game last year using Cocos 2d v2.1.
And I'd like to submit this game for now, but unfortunately, Apple don't allow it.

I need to add 64bit support feature in my game,which I tried to add in project settings.
But I can't submit it yet.

How to submit this project?
Must I create again using Cocos 2dx?

Please help me.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell or show us the actual error which you are getting. You are using cocos2d and not cocos2dx correct?

Please refer this link:
http://forum.cocos2d-spritebuilder.org/t/cocos2d-iphone-2-1-64-bit-fix/15919